# Using Firestore Triggers to Manage User Document Count

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If every *document* in a *collection* is a user resource that is limited, how can you ensure the user does not go over their assigned limit?

My first thought was to take advantage of the Firestore triggers to avoid building a real backend, but the triggers sometimes fire more than once even if the inputed data has not changed. I was comparing the new doc to the old doc and taking action if certain keys did not match but if GCP fires the same function twice I get double the result. In this case incrementing or decrementing counts.

The Firestore docs state:

> Events are delivered at least once, but a single event may result in multiple function invocations. Avoid depending on exactly-once mechanics, and write idempotent functions.

So in my situation the only solution I can think of is saving the event id's somewhere and ensuring they did not fire already. Or even worse doing a read on each call to count the current docs and adjust them accordingly (increasing read costs).

Whats a smart way to approach this?

Comment: "*So in my situation the only solution I can think of is saving the event id's somewhere and ensuring they did not fire already*: - this is a very common solution, and it generally why event IDs are provided: to avoid duplication of work in the face of retries which are designed to keep your data as consistent as possible in the face of inevitable errors.

Answer (score 0):

If reinvocations (which while possible are quite uncommon) are a concern for your use-case, you could indeed store the ID of the invocation event or something less frequent, like (depending on the use-case) the source document ID.